# sequential call using promise inside loop

Tags: javascript

i want to perform synchronous operation of functions using `promise`. I have loop that passes the data to be inserted to `insert` function and after inserting one row i want to check the no. of rows exists in table hence i am performing `select` operation.

But the issue is if there are 3 records then it inserts all 3 records and after that my select function gets executed. what i want is after insertion of one record select function gets called.

here is my pseudo code as entire code involves lot of operations

```
for(var i=0; data.length ; i++){

 self.executeFeedbackTrack(data);

}


executeFeedbackTrack:function(callInfo){
    var self=this;
   return  self.insertFeedbackTrack(callInfo).then(function(data){

                console.log("insertFeedbackTrack status "+status);

        return self.getFeedbackTrack();

    });
},

getFeedbackTrack :function(){

    return new Promise(function(resolve,reject){
         var objDBFeedbackTrack = new DBFeedbackTrack();
        objDBFeedbackTrack.selectFeedbackTrack(function(arrayCallRegisters){
            if(arrayCallRegisters){

            console.log("notification.js no. of feedbacks "+arrayCallRegisters.length);

            resolve(arrayCallRegisters.length);

            }

        });
    });


},
insertFeedbackTrack :function(callInfo){

return new Promise(function(resolve,reject){
     var objDBFeedbackTrack = new DBFeedbackTrack();
     objDBFeedbackTrack.insertFeedbackTrack(callInfo.callNumber,callInfo.callServiceType,function(status){

             resolve(status);
            $('#loader').hide();

     });
});

}
```

Comment: Please see provided answer.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

This can be solved by using a very handy JS library [Ramda](http://ramdajs.com/). Concept is to use two methods, one is [`R.partial`](http://ramdajs.com/docs/#partial) and another is [`R.pipeP`](http://ramdajs.com/docs/#pipeP).

First create a promises array from your `data` array, like following.

```
var promises = data.map(function(i) {
  return R.partial(sample, [i])
});
```

Then you can pass this promise to `R.pipeP`, so that it can be executed one after another. like below.

```
var doOperation = R.pipeP.apply(this, promises)
```

Please execute following snippet attached.

```js
// Sample promise returning function
function sample(d) {
  return new Promise(function(resolve, reject){
    setTimeout(function() {
      console.log('resolved for:' + d);
      resolve(d);
    }, 1000)
  })
}

// Sample data
var data = [1, 2, 3, 4, 5]

// Converting data array to promise array
var promises = data.map(function(i) {
  return R.partial(sample, [i])
});

var doOperation = R.pipeP.apply(this, promises)
doOperation();
```

```html
<script src="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/ramda/0.25.0/ramda.min.js"></script>
```

So in your case, the code will look like this

```
var promises = data.map(function(i) {
  return R.partial(self.executeFeedbackTrack, [i])
});
var doOperation = R.pipeP.apply(this, promises)
doOperation();
```

Answer (score 7):

The previous answer is good, but if you are using nodejs, or babel, or you are using only modern browsers. You can use an async-await pair, it is es8 stuff.

```
let insertFeedbackTrack = function(){ return new Promise(/***/)};
let getFeedbackTrack = function(){ return new Promise(/***/)};
let processResult = async function(data){
   let feedbacks = [];
   for(let i=0;i<data.length;i++){
      let insertedResult = await insertFeedbackTrack(data[i]);//perhaps you will return an id;
      let feedbackTrack = await getFeedbackTrack(insertedResult.id);
      feedbacks.push(feedbackTrack);
   }
   return feedbacks;
} 

processResult(data).then(/** do stuff */)
```

Answer (score 5):

It looks to me like this is caused by executing a series of asynchronous inserts, and assuming that the `get` of `insert n` (inside of a `.then()`) is called before `insert n+1` is executed. However, I'm not aware of any such guarantee, in JavaScript; all that I'm familiar with is that `then n` will be called after `insert n`, not that it would be called before `insert n+1`.

What I'd suggest is avoiding this mix of traditional and callback-based code, and instead put the iteration step inside `getFeedbackTrack().then`. Assuming this understanding of the issue is correct, then something like the following should work:

```
function iterate(i) {
    if (i < data.length) {
        obj.insertFeedbackTrack(data[i]).then(function(insertResult) {
            self.getFeedbackTrack().then(function(getResult) {
                // this line is the important one, replacing the `for` loop earlier
                iterate(i+1);
            });
        });
    }
}

iterate(0);
```

By doing that, you would guarantee that `insert` for the next element does not occur until the current `select` executes successfully.

Naturally, you may also want to restructure that to use chained `.then` instead of nested; I used nested rather than chained to emphasize the ordering of callbacks.

Comment: you are trying to replace for loop with the recursive function ?

Comment: Yep, exactly so - replace the for loop with a recursive chain of `then` callbacks, in order to force a specific ordering of the events/callbacks.

Comment: well i have to do lot of changes just to change the for loop , is there any workaround

Comment: Do you have synchronous versions of your functions, and can you afford to block the (sole) execution thread while running DB operations?

Answer (score 0):

Here's how I would sequentially call promises in a loop (I'm using ES7).
First, let's define some basic data:

```
const data = [0,1,2,3];
```

Then, let's simulate some long running process, so let's create a function that returns a Promise (you can think of this as a simulated network request, or whatever suits your needs)

```
const promiseExample = (item) =>
  new Promise((res) => {
    setTimeout(() => {
      console.log('resolved ', item);
    res(item);
  }, 1000);
});
```

Now, let's create an array of promises. What the next line of code does is: for every item in the array data, return a promise factory. A promise factory is a function that wraps a certain promise without running it.

```
const funcs = data.map(item => async () => await promiseExample(item));
```

Now, the actual code starts here. We need a function that does the actual serialization. Since it has to handle an array of promiseFactories, I split it in two functions, one for the serialization of a single promise, and one for handling an array of promiseFactories.

```
const serializePromise = promiseFactoryList =>
  promiseFactoryList.reduce(serialize, Promise.resolve([]));

const serialize = async (promise, promiseFactory) => {
  const promiseResult = await promise;
  const res = await promiseFactory();
  return [...promiseResult, res];
};
```

Now, you can simply call it like this:

```
serializePromise(funcs).then(res => {
    console.log('res', res);
});
```

As you can see, the code is pretty simple, elegant, functional, and doesn't need any external dependency. I hope this answers your question and helps you!

```js
const serializePromise = promiseFactoryList =>
  promiseFactoryList.reduce(serialize, Promise.resolve([]));

const serialize = async (promise, promiseFactory) => {
  const promiseResult = await promise;
  const res = await promiseFactory();
  return [...promiseResult, res];
};

const data = [0,1,2,3];

const promiseExample = (item) =>
  new Promise((res) => {
 setTimeout(() => {
   console.log('resolved ', item);
   res(item);
    }, 1000);
  });

const funcs = data.map(item => async () => await promiseExample(item))

serializePromise(funcs).then(res => {
  console.log('res', res);
});
```

Comment: @Hunt please check this out :)

Answer (score 0):

I use yield for such cases if using generator functions.

```
for(var i = 0; i < order.tasks.length; i++){
        if(order.tasks[i].customer_id === 0){
          var name = order.tasks[i].customer_name.split(" ")
          const customers = yield db.queryAsync(
            `INSERT INTO customers(
              business_id)
             VALUES(?)
            `,[order.business_id])
        }
      }
```

Or else I use self-calling functions in case of callbacks.

```
var i = 0;
(function loop() {
    if (i < data.length) {
        task_ids1.push([order.tasks[i].task_id])
        i++;
        loop();
    }
}());
```

Answer (score 0):

I ran into this problem recently and solved it as shown below. This is very similar to the answer by @Ethan Kaminsky, but only uses callbacks. This may be useful for people avoiding promises for whatever reason.

In my application the asynchronous function may fail and can safely be retried; I included this logic because it's useful and doesn't overly complicate the routine, but it is not exercised in the example.

```js
// Some callback when the task is complete
function cb(...rest) { window.alert( `${rest.join(', ')}` ) }

// The data and the function operating on the data
// The function calls "callback(err)" on completion
const data = [ 'dataset1', 'dataset2', 'dataset3' ]
const doTheThing = (thingDone) => setTimeout( thingDone, 1000 )

let i = -1                    // counter/interator for data[]
let retries = 20              // everything fails; total retry #

// The do-async-synchronously (with max retries) loop
function next( err ) {
    if( err ) {
        if( ! --retries ) return cb( 'too many retries' )
    } else if( ! data[++i] ) return cb( undefined, 'done-data' )

    console.log( 'i is', i, data[i] )
    doTheThing( next, data[i] )       // callback is first here
}

// start the process
next()
```